# How to clear elements created programmatically from UITableViewCell before it's reuse

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am writing an application in Swift 3 that involves a UITableView. I am creating my table view cells pragmatically. The problem I am experiencing is that the cell's label text is persistent after the .reloadData() function. Is there a function to clear all elements and formatting from a cell before it's use? I am instantiating the UILabel via code and cannot access it across iterations. Unfortunately, I have already put a ton of time into programmatically creating the table, so I'd like to avoid going back and making a cell class if possible. 
I am planning to use a function something like this:

```
var label: UILabel
                if reloadCount > 0 {
                    //clear all formatting from the cell
                }

                    label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 0, width: self.screenWidth - 100, height: 50))
                    label.textAlignment = .center
                    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
                    label.textColor = UIColor(red: 127.0/255, green: 140.0/255, blue: 142.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
                    label.font = UIFont(name: "Tahoma", size: CGFloat(22))
                    label.numberOfLines = 0
                    label.tag = Int(self.thoughtFeed[indexPath.row].dbId!)!
                    label.text = thoughtFeed[indexPath.row].thoughtText!.fromBase64()
                    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    label.addGestureRecognizer(labelTap)
                    cell.addSubview(label)
```

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: How are you storing the data that will be loaded into your tableView? Show us some of your `UITableViewDataSource` code.

Comment: clear your array,

Comment: Are you planning on running this code in `cellForRowAt` ?

Comment: I have cleared the array. The problem seems to be that the cell's content is not being cleared before it is reused. Therefore, when I add a new label to the cell (once it is time for it to be reused) the labels are stacked upon one another. Is there a function to remove all content from the cell before it is reused?

Comment: No, you'll somehow need to "remember" the uilabel and remove it before you reuse the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to somehow "remember" the `UILabel` and either reuse it or remove it. Since you say you don't want to subclass `UITableViewCell` you can use tags to get a reference to your label. In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do something like this:

```
if let label = cell.viewWithTag(42) as? UILabel {
    // now you have a reference to the existing label.
    // Just update the text (or whatever you need to do)
} else {
    label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 0, width: self.screenWidth - 100, height: 50))

    // add a tag so we can remember it when we dequeue a cell later
    label.tag = 42
    cell.addSubview(label)    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will give this a try in a little and let you know how it worked.

Comment: @iamnickpitoniak any luck?